# Android Listview issue ( Notifydatasetchanged())

Tags: android, listview

maybe its not hard but i cant solve the my list problem. I got a Listview populating from list.

```
     @Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    if (requestCode == 2) {

        String kpn = data.getStringExtra("kupeno");
        txtddtyKupeNo.setText(kpn);


    }
    if (resultCode == 3) {
        ArrayList<BuzagiKayitDBean> arraylist = data.getParcelableArrayListExtra("mylist");

        adapter = new BuzagiListAdapter(dty, BuzagiKayitActivity.this);

        for (BuzagiKayitDBean item : arraylist) {
            dty.add(item);
        }

        if (buzlist.getCount() > 0) {

            buzlist.setAdapter(adapter);
            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        } else {
            buzlist.setAdapter(adapter);
        }

    }
}
```

and nothing changing at listview ? what im doing wrong ?  tyvm.

Edit ( Changed like this and still not refreshing. I got 2 items onlist but shows only 1 )
Edit 2 ( Upgraded the code but still not working damn)

Comment: are you set adapter some else exept in else ? because you populate your List and you must set adapter first in if clause

Comment: Are u able to show listview items? What u want to do? can u explain a bit more?

Comment: what if buzlist.getCount() > 0 and your  adapter  is null. have you think about that?

Comment: Try this set the adapter again in if condition and do a notifydatasetChanged() call

Comment: still not working :(

Comment: because you didnt enter in else clause and your adapter is not initialize at all

Comment: Just make a try remove the whole if else condition. 
adapter = new BuzagiListAdapter(dty, BuzagiKayitActivity.this);
buzlist.setAdapter(adapter);
adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

I know its not the right way just try once.

Comment: try to  set this line adapter = new BuzagiListAdapter(dty, BuzagiKayitActivity.this); before for loop.

Comment: so what i should do ? can u show with a little  code ?

Answer (score 1):

First,init your `adapter` as soon as possible,add call `setAdapter();`
Then ,when you data is prepared ,add one method for you adapter just like `appendList(List<T> list)` to append data to your adapter!

```
public void appendList(DailyStories dailyStories) {
    //todo addList()
    notifydatasetChanged();
}
```

I recommended you to use `RecycleView` to replace `ListView`,it's more powerful!!

Answer (score 0):

You must change your logic because if every time  you enter of this peace of code  `buzlist.getCount() > 0`, your `adapter` will be aways `null` you didn`t initialize or set the adapter.Or either way  you must set adapter and when your list is **>0** .